# Add a column to PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array created from a mysqli select statment that contains multiple values. (list of customers)
Then I have a another select containing only one value which I've also stored in another array. When that's done I want to store the information in my DB.
It's a list of customers that should be linked to the same product.

Now I want to extend the first array with a new column with a value from my other array. (same value for each row of the first array. I can't find any way to do this despite serious googling...
Code: (after db connection) Session values comes from another PHP script and are correct.

```
session_start();
$product = $_SESSION['prod_name'];
$ka      = $_SESSION['ka'];
//print_r($_SESSION);

$customers = mysqli_query($link,"
SELECT cust_id FROM customers
INNER JOIN ka_chain on ka_chain.chain_id=chain
WHERE ka_chain.name='$ka'");

$cid=array(); //array with multiple records
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customers)) {
    $cid = $row;
    print_r($cid);
}

$prod_id = mysqli_query($link,
"SELECT prod_id FROM products
WHERE prod_name='$product'") ;
$pid     = mysqli_fetch_array($prod_id); //array with only one row.
```

And now what?....

Comment: You are overwriting your `$cid` array in the loop. Apart from that you need to clarify your question, perhaps with an example, because it's hard to tell what you want to do.

Comment: We need a print_r of the current structure and the desired structure.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is correct the insertion of the $row into the $cid array. Change it to $cid[] = $row

one customer can have many products and one product can be bought by many customers. So we have a many to many relation here. You need a third table that will join the two and so you don't need to add a row but you need a new table that will store the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Print_r for $cid array look as follows:
Array ( [cust_id] => 2 ) Array ( [cust_id] => 8 )
Currently I have 2 customer id's in the array. My wish is to add another column called "product_id" to the array and then add the same value for each row. (value from $pid).
Then the new array should be stored in a table.

Answer (score 0):

An update, I solved it the following way: (with comments in code)
Thanks for the help and good ideas!

```
session_start();
$product=$_SESSION['prod_name'];
$ka=$_SESSION['ka'];

//get customer assigned to ka chain
$customers = mysqli_query($link,"
SELECT cust_id FROM customers
INNER JOIN ka_chain on ka_chain.chain_id=chain
WHERE ka_chain.name='$ka'");
// get product id
$prod_id = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT prod_id FROM products
WHERE prod_name='$product'") ;
//add product id to array and convert to int
$pid=mysqli_fetch_array($prod_id);
$pid_int = (int) $pid['prod_id'];

// Create new array to add product id to customers
$cust_product = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customers)) {
  $item['cust_id'] = (int)$row['cust_id'];
  $item['product_id'] =$pid_int;
  $cust_product[]=$item;
}
 //insert data to new array
if(is_array($cust_product)){
$sql = "INSERT INTO cust_products (cust_id, product_id) values ";
$valuesArr = array();
foreach($cust_product as $row){
    $c_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $row['cust_id'] );
    $p_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $row['product_id'] );
    $valuesArr[] = "('$c_id', '$p_id')";
}
$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use array_merge() at this site http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php